# How to remove quotes from output field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple 'click to tweet' tool which takes input, adds quotes in preview and tweet it on a button click.
http://codepen.io/markoJurisic/pen/yJgVez

Everything seems fine with input and output fields, except when you delete all text from the input field, quotes remain. I've tried to remove them, but unsuccessfully. 
This is my jquery code for the output field:

```
var $src = $('#input'),
    $dst = $('#output');

    $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.html('&ldquo;' + $src.val() + '&rdquo;');
    });
```

Also, is there any way to remove url from a generated tweet? e.g. if I type "Hello World!" and click to tweet to premade a message without a codepen url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check if the is anything in the input:

```
$src.on('input', function () {
    $dst.html($src.val() ? '&ldquo;' + $src.val() + '&rdquo;' : '');
});
```

For the url exclusion you mentioned, if you are intending on having the user *tweet* instead of *share*, you should then be using [intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents) - to do this simply change the url:

```
tweetUrl = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(phrase);
```

Note the use of `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet` instead of `https://twitter.com/share`

[**Updated Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxRpKr)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying for an hour via if - else, but obviously "the wrong way" :)